# How To $pull From Deeply Nested Document (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

I need to delete a location object from the locations array. It is deeply nested. I followed mongoose documentation but my attempts didn't work:

```js
lists = [{
  "listName": "Test",
  "_id": "8d55f0afe545a0178c320706",
  "listId": "5fd9a3bef6c39b2f9c4df65b",
  "date": "12/15/2020",
  "dueDate": "2020-11-18",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemNumber": 123,
      "description": "item123",
      "onHand": 60,
      "_id": "13dd1f26ecd2baeb61b3b455",
      "locations": [
        {
          "locationName": "loc1",
          "count": 10,
          "_id": "50a2c969465ba8010bd48977"
        },
        {
          "locationName": "loc2",
          "count": 20,
          "_id": "51c2f1d25311dc8fabdbf604a59b"
        },
        {
          "locationName": "Loc3",
          "count": 30,
          "_id": "7cb0c1f51a91c384846d65f8b2ae"
        }
      ]
    },
    {more lists}
```

Attempt:

```js
router.post("/lists/deleteLoc", (req, res) => {
      const {
        listId,
        list_id,
        item_id,
        location_id
      } = req.body;
      List.updateOne({
            "lists.listId": listId,
            "lists._id": list_id
          }, {
            $pull: {
              "lists.$.items": {
                locations: {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    _id: location_id
                  })
                .then(() => res.json({
                  msg: "location removed"
                }))
                .catch((err) => res.status(400).json({
                  msg: "Error: " + err
                }));
              });
```

If the request location_id was "7cb0c1f51a91c384846d65f8b2ae" it should delete the last location from the array. The desired result:

```js
lists = [{
  "listName": "Test",
  "_id": "8d55f0afe545a0178c320706",
  "listId": "5fd9a3bef6c39b2f9c4df65b",
  "date": "12/15/2020",
  "dueDate": "2020-11-18",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemNumber": 123,
      "description": "item123",
      "onHand": 60,
      "_id": "13dd1f26ecd2baeb61b3b455",
      "locations": [
        {
          "locationName": "loc1",
          "count": 10,
          "_id": "50a2c969465ba8010bd48977"
        },
        {
          "locationName": "loc2",
          "count": 20,
          "_id": "51c2f1d25311dc8fabdbf604a59b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {more lists}
```

I've tried basically all variations of this, but none have worked.

I'm also not sure if making a router.post or an axios.post request for deletion is correct. Should this be axios.delete and router.delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this in one of my similar DB and worked!

```
List.updateOne({ "listId": yourListId },
        {
            '$pull': {
                'items.$[item].locations': { "_id": yourLocationId }
            }
        }, {
        "arrayFilters": [
            {
                "item._id": yourItemId
            }
        ]
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json({ message: "Updated" })
        }
    })
}
```

You've to put the values that're inside your DB from the object that you want to delete.

So if you want to delete the object with

> "locationname" : "Loc3"

You should use

```
var yourListId = "5fd9a3bef6c39b2f9c4df65b";
var yourItemId = "13dd1f26ecd2baeb61b3b455";
var yourLocationId = "7cb0c1f51a91c384846d65f8b2ae";
```

Try it out!

Comment: You're A GENIUS! Thank you. It worked and I learned something valuable with the array filters!